# How to hide content one and show content two?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, visibility

I have a problem here. I'd like to hide one content on my website and show next content with jQuery. I've got just 2 content divs.

So basically what I'd like to do is...

1) When I open the website `<div id="content2"></div>` hides as well as `<div id="content2_bottom"></div>`.

2) When I click on the link `<a href="#" id="click_to_change_content">Click</a>` ...the  `<div id="content1"></div>` with a `<div id="content1_bottom"></div>` hide and content2 is visible.

My code:

```
$(function(){
   if ($("#content1").is(":visible")) {
      $("#content2").hide();
      $("#content2_bottom").hide();
   }
   $("#click_to_change_content").on("click", function(){
      $("#content1").hide();
      $("#content2").show();
      $("#content1_bottom").hide();
      $("#content2_bottom").show();
   });
});
```

What it does is actually it swaps content but it swaps it right back so I see just content1 all the time. I'm sure I have something bad, but I'm just a beginner with jQuery, so I don't know what I've done bad.

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of for this example is using `jQuery`'s `.toggle()` function. As long as one of these two divs is hidden when the page loads, you only need a single function to hide one and show the other when you press the button. Take this code for instance:

Html:

```
<div id="content1">
  <label class="label label-success">Content 1</label>
</div>

<div id="content2" style="display:none;">
  <label class="label label-danger">Content 2</label>
</div>

<div>
  <button id="button" class="btn btn-primary">Toggle!</button>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="#" id="link">Toggle!</a>
</div>
```

Javascript (with jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button, #link").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#content1, #content2").toggle();
  });
});
```

Instead of worrying about checking the visibility status, assume that one is always hidden, `.toggle()` will switch which one is show to the user when you press the toggle button.

Here is a Bootply show how it works:

[Bootply - Toggle](http://www.bootply.com/33xeVoKZnL)

Hope that helps!

**Edited**

Shows the link functionality (basically the same, added `e.preventDefault()` to stop any page movement.)

Comment: Thank you, it really works and it's easier to understand and see what it does. But these toggle "things" works just with buttons... do you know something similar that works with links too? :)

Comment: It would be the same thing with a link, you would simply have to stop the page from going anywhere. I'll edit it into my answer for ya :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I already have it after like.. 2 hrs or so. I was trying to do that without asking anything here :P I could save some time... eh :D

Comment: Yeah, sometimes you can get some quick answers here, but it's always better to try it yourself, fail and then ask for help. You don't learn otherwise, and if you don't learn, what's the point? :)

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Hope more people were like you! :D Thanks one more time!

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to use css classes to show & hide your elements and toggle them with jquery. Example:

```
<div class="content-section shown">Content 1</div>

<div class="content-section">Content 2</div>

<button id="click_to_change_content">click_to_change_content</button>
```

css:

```
.content-section {
    display: none;
}

.content-section.shown {
    display: block;
}
```

jquery:

```
$(function(){
   $("#click_to_change_content").on("click", function(){
          $(".content-section").toggleClass("shown");
   });
});
```

#### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/13sn0j66/1/)

---

But sticking with your html structure:

html:

```
<div id="content1">Content 1</div>
<div id="content1_bottom">Content 1 bottom</div>

<div id="content2">Content 2</div>
<div id="content2_bottom">Content 2 bottom</div>

<button id="click_to_change_content">click_to_change_content</button>
```

jquery:

```
$(function(){
   $("#content2, #content2_bottom").hide();
   $("#click_to_change_content").on("click", function(){
      $("#content2, #content2_bottom, #content1, #content1_bottom").toggle();
   });
});
```

#### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ub8vyrx9/)

Comment: in your first example why not use toggleClass("shown") instead of toggle()?

Comment: @user3334690 That was a mistake. Corrected. Thanks!